# No se llegar a una instancia de firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

estoy desarrollando una app Java en Android Studio. Los usuarios de esta son médicos que pueden registrar embarazadas de la siguiente manera:

```
private void cargarEmbarazadaFirebase() {

    String nombre=etNombre.getText().toString();
    String apellidos=etApellidos.getText().toString();
    String alergias=etAlergias.getText().toString();
    String fechaDeNacimiento=etFechaDeNacimiento.getText().toString();
    String embarazosPrevios=etEmbarazosPrevios.getText().toString();
    String frecAlcohol=etAlcohol.getText().toString();
    String drogas=etDrogas.getText().toString();
    String fumadora=etFumadora.getText().toString();

    Embarazada embarazada = new Embarazada(nombre, apellidos,alergias,fechaDeNacimiento,embarazosPrevios,frecAlcohol
    ,drogas,fumadora);
    Embarazos.child("Pacientes/"+embarazada.getNombre()+embarazada.getApellidos()).setValue(embarazada);
}
```

Y la referencia a la base de datos es la siguiente:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    Embarazos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usuario").child(user.getUid());
```

Posteriormente, estas embarazadas las listo en un ListView en una activity llamada misPacientes, he conseguido que al clickar en una embarazada me la lleve a otra activity en la que no quiero recuperar sus datos, los datos los quiero recuperar desde el boton datos de esta activity.

Mi listView clickable:

```
lvEmbarazadas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Embarazada embarazada= listPerson.get(position);
            Intent intent=new Intent(misPacientes.this,paciente.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("embarazada",embarazada);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Cuando clicko un elemento de ese listview quiero aparecer en una activity donde me ofrezaca las opciones de tres botones que tengo en un layout, uno de esos botones es DATOS, al clickar en datos me gustaría recibir los datos de la embarazada que he seleccionado.

Pongo una foto de como tengo montada la base de datos:

[image: Por así decirlo quiero llegar hasta donde pone PaulVazquez Rodruiguez y obtener los distintos child que tiene anidados]

Por así decirlo quiero llegar hasta donde pone PaulVazquez Rodruiguez y obtener los distintos child que tiene anidados. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de anemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que deberias hacer es que cuando clicas ese elemento de la lista que te lleva a la otra actividad, podes enviar con putExtra el ID del paciente en la base de datos, de esta forma cuando clicas en datos (tu layout) envias una solicitud a Firebase con el ID que enviaste a esa actividad el cual identifica al usuario/paciente que quieres recuperar esos datos.

Ese ID te va a ayudar a poder navegar en Firebase hacia tu paciente

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo he solucionado hace un momento.